# How can i connect to database in Spring batch

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-batch

I am working on an application. I am using DB-repository.xml to configure my database. I am using MYSQL for it. I created a database named batchsample and created a table called employee which has 4 fields. My application is connecting to the database but it is not taking the table which i have created, in fact it is taking some other table called batch_job_instance. How can i connect my app to the created table employee.
I have used the following in my DB-repository.xml:

```
<bean id="jobRepository-dataSource"
   class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/batchsample" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.** But you can change the prefix.

From documentation :

> Only the table prefix is configurable. The table and column names are not.

**Source:**

- [Spring Batch Reference Documentation > Changing the Table Prefix](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#repositoryTablePrefix)